# Github workflow "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"

Tags: github, github-actions

### Background

I have a small elixir project and I am trying to use GithubWorkflow to have a nice pipeline and automate some actions.

### Problem

However I can't even get it started as I get the following error:

```
 Setup elixir
1s
    AUCTION_HOUSE_TOKEN: ***
Run actions/setup-elixir@v1
  with:
    elixir-version: 1.10-otp-22
    otp-version: 22.1
    install-hex: true
    install-rebar: true
  env:
    COOKIE: ***
    TOKEN: ***
##[error]Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

### Code

I think my workflow might be incorrect, could someone help figure out what's wrong?

```
name: build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

env: 
  AUCTION_HOUSE_COOKIE: ${{ secrets.MARKET_MANAGER_WM_COOKIE }}
  AUCTION_HOUSE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MARKET_MANAGER_WM_XCSRFTOKEN }}

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup elixir
      uses: actions/setup-elixir@v1
      with:
        elixir-version: '1.10-otp-22' # Define the elixir version [required]
        otp-version: '22.1' # Define the OTP version [required]
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: mix deps.get
    - name: Run Tests
      run: mix test
    - name: Run credo code analyser
      run: mix credo --strict
    - name: Run typechecks
      run: mix dialyzer
    - name: Build executable
      run: mix escript.build
      env: 
        MIX_ENV: prod
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary

The elixir version in the file was *wrong*. It should have:

```
      with:
        elixir-version: '1.10.4 # Define the elixir version [required]
        otp-version: '22.1' # Define the OTP version [required]
```

Instead of the current content.

### RCA

So this one was interesting. When it comes to elixir versions, because I use asdf as my version manager, I am allowed to pick the best version (the most optimized) for the erlang setup I have.

How do I know which elixir version is the best for, lets say, erlang 22.1?
Well, I use bob's list:

https://bobs-list.kobrakai.de/#version_v1.10

And while this is fine and it does work on my machine and in docker files and so on, Github Action **wont accept it**. Github Actions takes its elixir version's from here:

https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases

And as you can see, there no official release called "1.10-otp-22"

So, instead of the current content, the file should instead have:

```
with:
        elixir-version: '1.10.4' # Define the elixir version [required]
        otp-version: '22.1' # Define the OTP version [required]
```